# Delimit Get-ChildItem output with Single Quotes

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell, I am attempting to get a list of folders and files beginning at a certain level in the folder hierarchy like this:

Get-ChildItem -Path ./trunk -Recurse -include *.rpt

Because file names can contain spaces, I need to surround file name with single quotes so I can feed those file names into a Java program for processing:

java -cp . SomeJavaPgm (Get-ChildItem -Path ./tags -Recurse -include *.rpt)

How would I either define a PowerShell function and call it to delimit the output of the Get-ChildItem cmdlet with single quotes or pipeline the output of Get-ChildItem so that it would delimit the output with single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial trial, as absolute path.

```
Get-Childitem -Path ./tags -Recurse -include *.rp | % {
$a = $_.fullname -replace '"', '""'; "'$a'"
}
```

Using the double aphostrophes

```
Get-Childitem -Path ./tags -Recurse -include *.rp | % {
    $a = $_.fullname -replace '"', '""'; "`"$a`""
}
```

Comment: Unexpected token ''$a'' in expression or statement.
At C:\Workspace\Source_Code\publish.ps1:12 char:81
+     Get-Childitem -Path ./tags -Recurse -include *.rpt | % {$a = $_.fullname "'$a'"} <<<<

Comment: That was it.  How would you double quotes, would you need to use the ` escape character "`"$a`""?

Comment: $a = $a -replace '"', '""' # I merged it into the above

Comment: You mean like this: Get-Childitem -Path ./trunk -Recurse -include *.rpt | % {$a = $a -replace '"', '""' }

Comment: You must add keep the ; "'$a'" otherwise nothing will be output

Comment: Why doesn't the grave(escape) character work in this case: Get-Childitem -Path ./trunk -Recurse -include *.rpt | % {$a = $_.fullname; "`"$a`""}

Comment: That is because the editing tool wants to escape it, I replaced it with the word grave-mark. Why doesn't the grave(escape) character work in this case: Get-Childitem -Path ./trunk -Recurse -include .rpt | % {$a = $.fullname; "grave-mark" $a grave-mark""}

Comment: In your code the underscore after the $ is missing. See my edited answer